# Windows Spellchecking API returns no supported languages

Tags: c++, windows, api, delphi, spell-checking

I started to look at the [Spellchecker API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869853(v=vs.85).aspx) available in Windows 8 and newer (I'm running Windows 10). However something i'm struggling with after creating the ISpellCheckerFactory is, that "SupportedLanguages" returns no elements. And i'm not sure why this happens.

%Appdata%\Microsoft\Spelling
Is empty, too.

If asked for, i can add some code snippets but for now it seems more like a fundamental problem. I thought there is at least a Dictionary/Provider installed for the installed OS-Language.

Comment: It looks like your problem is that you just don't have any installed. I have two directories in `%Appdata%\Microsoft\Spelling`: `en-US` and `en-CA`.

Comment: On a side note, it's rather scary what I've found in `default.dic`... A listing of words and names I've used in the past, many of which I'm shocked to find. For example, names of old friends I haven't spoken to in many years.

Comment: @JerryDodge it actually seems, those are not the full dictionaries but the "UserDefined" ones, were any modification you make(when adding a word to the dictionary in an application like word) seem to end up.

Comment: Indeed, my shock though is actually what words I've found there. I haven't even owned my computer for as long as some of these private names I see.

Comment: @JerryDodge Do you login with a Live-Account?